Как появилась первая репутация?
Как на Stack Overflow на русском появилась первая репутация?
Давайте не будем учитывать переход с английского SO на русский участников с репутацией.
Я знаю про возможность принятия ответов, но были ли другие способы?

Это интересный вопрос, кстати. Alexolut вроде как-то раскопал, что Николас (создатель сайта) на этапе начального наполнения сайта принимал свои ответы, но отметку ставил от лица другого пользователя, так что за это в обход обычных правил начислялась репа. Плюс были и "официальные марионетки", от которых на начальном этапе задавались вопросы (попробуйте их найти среди пользователей с самой старой датой регистрации).

@MSDN.WhiteKnight нашел в чате. Про переход с английского SO не очень понял: репа между сайтами не шарится, но может быть бонус ассоциации. Репа в общем случае появляется одинаково: голосуют за сообщения и принятие ответов. Это база.

@αλεχολυτ, ещё правки. Правда тогда их было не кому проверять

@αλεχολυτ, про переход с английского SO я имел ввиду, что если у тебя больше 300 репы, то ты получаешь на новом сайте со старта 100 репы

100 репы это и есть "бонус ассоциации" о котором я говорил выше, только там 200 репы надо иметь номинально, а не 300.

Сначала был хэш-код, потом из него получилась ветка StackOverflow. Все участники хэш-кода перешли со своей репутацией.  Насколько я помню (но могу ошибаться) на начальном этапе в хэш-коде было 2 участника (они же создатели сайта) Николас и stanislav. Они провели начальное наполнение сайте вопросами и ответами, историю которых  можно посмотреть в их аккаунтах

@avp, были административные твинки, при переносе на ru.SO они были слиты, репутация пересчитана. Вот например вопрос с тремя отметившимися участниками: https://web.archive.org/web/20120519152331/http://hashcode.ru/questions/565/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-go В итоге все они стали Станиславом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/565. Если сильно захотеть, можно прикинуть сколько таких твинков было, если посчитать несуществующие учетки с малыми id.

На 2011 год сайт уже точно не выглядел пустым, кроме твинков было некоторое количество реальных участников. Как контрпример к примеру выше, вот вопрос из декабря 2010 с реальными участниками: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/579/1365

@insolor, ну, конечно, нет никаких сомнений в реальном функционировании хэшкода в 2010. Я подключился к сайту, почитал страничку с вопросами и ответы и задал свой первый вопрос 8 января 2011 (кстати, мой первый ответ тоже от этого числа) и мне быстро с интервалом в 11 минут  ответили Николас и Станислав (да, мой ответ был на вопрос Николаса, уже сопровождавшегося самоответом)

В общем, механизмы получения репутации на всех сайтах сети Stack Exchange одинаковы. Однако сайт в процессе своего становления проходит определённые стадии. В частности, на первых этапах присутствует фаза "Beta", для которой пороги на различные привилегии понижены. Например, на текущий момент (сентябрь 2024) можно посмотреть тут (скриншот прилагаю):



И сравнить их с существующими порогами на ruSO.
Т.о. если человек приходит с существующего сайта на новый и получает бонус ассоциации, он уже может голосовать "за" и пополнять чужую репутацию, даже не задавая вопросов и не публикуя ответов.
Для самого-самого начала (когда не было других сайтов, и неоткуда было получать бонус ассоциации) можно предположить, что пороги были ещё немного понижены. Но даже оставаясь в рамках порогов уровня "бета", участник, ответ которого был принят, получал +15 реп и мог после этого голосовать "за" и поднимать общее значение репутации пользователей сайта.
При этом известно, что на ранних этапах развития хэшкода (название сайта до того как он стал "Stack Overflow на русском") отмечать ответы принятыми могли не только авторы вопросов, но и модераторы.
